# Define how often MassTransit Consumer checks on the servicebus

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, servicebus

Im using MassTransit framework to manage my queues on service bus, its working fine, the problem is in 24 hours, the service bus had 6k requests, and the application is barely being used. Is there a way i can lower the amount of times MassTransit hits the service bus queue?

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host(Configuration["ServiceBus:Url"]
                    ,
                    z =>
                    {
                        z.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey",  Configuration["ServiceBus:Key"]);
                    });

                cfg.UseExtensionsLogging(provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>());

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "email-reset", e =>
                {
                    e.UseRetry(r => r.Interval(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)));
                    e.Consumer<ResetPasswordConsumer>(provider);

                });
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "email-successo", e =>
                {
                    e.UseRetry(r => r.Interval(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)));
                    e.Consumer<ResetPasswordSuccessConsumer>(provider);

                });
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "login-bloqueado", e =>
                {
                    e.UseRetry(r => r.Interval(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)));
                    e.Consumer<BlockedLoginConsumer>(provider);

                });
            }));
```

Comment: MassTransit doesn't poll, it uses the underlying client library which I believe uses AMQP. So MassTransit can't really control the traffic, it's handled entirely by the .NET client library provided by Microsoft.